# Python loop through list levels

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I am trying to loop through and merge of two lists that look like this:

```
T1 = [[['a',  1], ['c', 3]], [['e',  5], ['g', 7]], [['i',  9],['j', 11]]]
T2 = [[['m',  1], ['n', 5]], [['q',  7], ['r', 7]], [['t',  9],['u', 11]]]
```

So for example, `T1[0] = [['a',  1], ['c', 3]]`
`T2[0] = [['m',  1], ['n', 5]]`

I am writing what is essentially a merge algorithm, where I compare the second element in each list in T1[0][0] (the 1), with the second value in T2[0][0] (so 1 again). Essentially what I want is T1[0][0][0] and T2[0][0][0]. If they match, I merge the two values into a tuple {'a', 1, 'm'} (can also be a list if it makes things easier).

My confusion is stemming from the fact that I don't know  how to best loop through T1 and T2 without running it 3 times: (T1[0], T2[0]), (T1[1], T2[1]), (T1[2], T2[2])

Is there a way to elegantly loop through T1 and T2 so that I can go through each sublist in T1 and T2 and perform the check and merge?

Note: the data is already sorted, and I am not looking to use libraries. I want to know if I can do this myself.

##Update##
So I know it is a `for` loop, however the below code is as far as i can get, and it is throwing me a `list index out of range` as shown below

```
result = []
i = j = 0

while True:
    for s_T1 in T1:
        for s_T2 in T2:
            if s_T1[i][1] < s_T2[j][1]: ### error at this line
                i = i + 1

            elif  s_T1[i][1] > s_T2[j][1]:
                j = j + 1

            elif s_T1[i][1] == s_T2[j][1]:
                result.append(s_T1[i][0], str(s_T1[i][0), s_T2[j][0])
                i = i + 1
                j = j + 1
                
            if i == len(T1) or j == len(T2):
                break

return result
```

What the code should return is:

```
[[['a', 1, 'm']], [['g', 7, 'q'], ['g', 7, 'r']], [['i', 9, 't'], ['j', 11, 'u']]]
```

So, look at the integer in `['e',  5]` in T1, compare it to `['q',  7]` in T2, since 5 is smaller than 7, move to the next value in T1. if they match, append. And the other way around - if the value in T1 is greater than the value in T2, move to the next value in T1.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Also update your question with a required output given the sample input you have.

Comment: The result `['e', 5, 'n']` are not in the same "index" in both of the lists, is this a mistake, or should each index in `T1` be compared against each index of `T2`?

Comment: @quamrana i have updated my question. Any help with my loop is also appreciated

Comment: @HampusLarsson apologies this was a mistake, i have fixed it now. T1[0] should only be compared to T2[0], T1[1] only with T2[1], T1[2] only with T2[2]

Comment: @soapycat Then I assume that `['g', 7, 'q']` shouldn't be there either correct?

Comment: You get an error because your break statement is inside the nested loop. When i or j reaches the limit, the break stops the nested loop but not the parent one which continues and executes the nested loop again producing an error, as i or j is already out of limit

Comment: @HampusLarsson no, `['g', 7, 'q']` should be there as it is matching with 7 in both tables. the number in T1 should look at the number in T2, if T1 is greater, then move on to the next value in T2. If T1 is less, then move to the next value in T1. if they match, then print. i believe my code does that above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
def task(T1,T2):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(T1)):
        for k in range(2):
            for l in range(2):
                if T1[i][k][1]==T2[i][l][1]:
                    result.append([T1[i][k][0], T1[i][k][1],T2[i][l][0]]) 
    return result

task(T1,T2)
```

When run it results to:

```
[['a', 1, 'm'], ['g', 7, 'q'], ['g', 7, 'r'], ['i', 9, 't'], ['j', 11, 'u']]
```

as indicated in your question

Comment: you can do things like `T2[i][l][1]` ?? Every time I tried to do it, it would throw me an error! Must not have been doing it right. Is this a standard practice?

Comment: You can definitely do it as long the data stucture (the depth of it) allows it.
Have you tested the answers? If yes, please accept some, in case it answers the question properly.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

`zip` ties together multiple iterables so you can iterate through them in lock-step, which is what it seems you're looking for:

```
>>> result = []
>>> for i, j in zip(T1, T2):
...   sub = []
...   for x, y in zip(i, j):
...     if x[1] == y[1]:
...       sub.append((x[0], x[1], y[0]))
...   if sub:
...     result.append(sub)
...
>>> result
[[('a', 1, 'm')], [('g', 7, 'r')], [('i', 9, 't'), ('j', 11, 'u')]]
```

Comment: Not quite, i apologise i wasn't very clear in how i am looping. I have updated my loop and  match requirements.